# Why the openCV's samples dose not work in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'am trying to use opencv(2.4.10) samples in visual studio 2012 for c++.
for example I try to run display_image.cpp (from opencv\sources\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\introduction\display_image).I debug it with the command arguments of an image like E:\image\can.jpg but it dont show the image, so I change a part of code as in the below and it show the image.
source:

```
Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

after change:

```
//Mat image;
//image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // Read the file
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], 0);
Mat image(img)  ;
```

that was what I can handle it but now I want to run SURF_detector.cpp (from opencv\sources\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\features2D ) which need tow image to debug so I change the code where it take images like which is on top(that handle reading image) but where the code try to process the SURF algoritm it gave me an error as below image:

[image]

the source is like below:

```
/**
* @file SURF_detector
* @brief SURF keypoint detection + keypoint drawing with OpenCV functions
* @author A. Huaman
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void readme();

/**
* @function main
* @brief Main function
*/

int main( int argc,      // Number of strings in array argv
        char *argv[],   // Array of command-line argument strings
        char *envp[] )  // Array of environment variable strings
 {
//if( argc != 3 )
//{ readme(); return -1; }

//Mat img_1 = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
//Mat img_2 = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

IplImage *img1 = cvLoadImage(argv[1], 0);
Mat img_1(img1);
IplImage *img2 = cvLoadImage(argv[2], 0);
Mat img_2(img2);

if( !img_1.data || !img_2.data )
 { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

 //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
 int minHessian = 400;

 SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

 std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

 detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
 detector.detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

 //-- Draw keypoints
 Mat img_keypoints_1; Mat img_keypoints_2;

 drawKeypoints( img_1, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );
 drawKeypoints( img_2, keypoints_2, img_keypoints_2, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );

 //-- Show detected (drawn) keypoints
 imshow("Keypoints 1", img_keypoints_1 );
 imshow("Keypoints 2", img_keypoints_2 );

 waitKey(0);

 return 0;
}

/**
* @function readme
*/
void readme()
 { std::cout << " Usage: ./SURF_detector <img1> <img2>" << std::endl; }
```

HOW CAN I FIXED IT ??????

Comment: try \\ in image pathnames

Comment: thanks but I have try \\ before but there is no different.It seems that I have an dll problem as it's in the error image link

Comment: Why you are using `IplImage `?

Comment: Why you're modifying the sample??. The title is misleading.

Comment: because when the sample compile it does not show anything but when I change the code it show the images but is you say the sample must compile correctly I think, I must configure opencv correctly that i don't find a complete guide for it

Comment: ok, if the IplImage thing worked, but not imread - your problem is completely elsewhere. please go and **triple** check, if you're not accidentally are mixing opencv debug/release libs (or linking the wrong ones). imread is using a std:string to find the image, your prob shows typical symptoms of getting vtables in the std c++ libs wrong. (and please get rid of the IplImage* stuff **now**. it's not a fix!

Comment: I don't understand you.Would you please explain more?                                     
And do you know a complete guide that says how to configure opencv 2.4.10 for visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got opencv instllated. Let's say you want to run `SURF_descriptor.cpp`

This example needs the following .dlls (Release mode; for debug mode add d before the dot )

```
opencv_core2410.dll 
opencv_features2d2410.dll
opencv_flann2410.dll
opencv_highgui2410.dll
opencv_imgproc2410.dll
opencv_ml2410.dll
opencv_nonfree2410.dll
opencv_objdetect2410.dll
opencv_ocl2410.dll
```

Now you need to tell the compiler where are the header files. In my case

```
D:\CPP_Libraries\opencv_2.4.10\build\include
```

Next you need to tell the linker where are .libs. In my case

```
D:\CPP_Libraries\opencv_2.4.10\build\x86\vc12\lib
```

Now open the visual studio command prompt and type ( this is for release mode )

```
cl /EHsc SURF_descriptor.cpp /Fetest.exe /I D:\CPP_Libraries\opencv_2.4.10\build\include /link /LIBPATH:D:\CPP_Libraries\opencv_2.4.10\build\x86\vc12\lib opencv_core2410.lib opencv_highgui2410.lib opencv_features2d2410.lib  opencv_nonfree2410.lib
```

The aforementioned line will generate `test.exe`
To run it, you need two pictures. I'm using baboon.jpg which is

[image]

From the cmd, type

```
>test baboon.jpg baboon.jpg
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Do you know  a complete guide that says how to configure opencv 2.4.10 for visual studio?

Comment: Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZvjTTK9zTw. Please if this answers your question, mark this post as an anwser.